# Ruby On Rails Active Admin Create Action "Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, action, activeadmin

I have a problem with updating one field in Active Admin Create Controller Action.
My code:

```
params[:document].merge!({ createdby: current_user.id })
create!
redirect_to admin_documents_path, :notice => "Document added!"
```

I need after update attribute createdby to save a document and to redirect to admin_documents path.

But I am getting the error:

> Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action.
>   Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most
>   once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate
>   execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after
>   redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and
>   return".

And if I remove last line :"redirect_to admin_documents_path, :notice => "Document added!""

Then I am redirected to create page  (which is blank).

So, problem is with updating field in create action and redirection after.

Conntroller:

```
def create

  if File.exist?(Rails.root.join('uploads','',params[:document][:link]))
    redirect_to admin_documents_path, :notice => "Document with name #{params[:document][:link]} already exists. Please rename it and upload again!"
  else
    uploaded_io = params[:document][:content]
    File.open(Rails.root.join('uploads', '', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
      file.write(uploaded_io.read)
    end

    params[:document].merge!({ createdby: current_user.id })
    create!
    redirect_to admin_documents_path, :notice => "Document added!"

  end
end
```

In controller I am uploading new document and checking for existing on file system, updating one field and saving document on file system  and document attributes into db.

Comment: Can you post the entire controller?

Comment: Updated with entire controller

Comment: What this method `create!` is doing?

Comment: Its save value to db. I tried some other solutions but only that works!

Comment: Can you show the code of `create!` method? It seems that there is a render or redirect inside it.

Comment: Oh no that is rails command.

Comment: It seems that you are calling the action recursively. Could you try to simply remove that line `create!` and try again?

Comment: If removed than value createdby is not saved in db.